# Iterate through mongo cursor to list all values in Meteor Blaze?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, cursor, meteor-blaze

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!!! I have an app that is uploading a csv to mongo and then publishing it within meteor. In the Template.onCreated I am subscribing to it and in the Template.helper I am trying to iterate through the mongo cursor to get the values to display in a table.

```
Template.table.onCreated(function() {
  Template.instance().subscribe('contacts');
});

Template.table.helpers({
  contact() {
    var contactCursor = Contacts.find();
    return contactCursor;
  }
});
```

I have tried to cursor.fetch() and map but nothing renders or chrome crashes. My table looks like this:

```
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{#each contact}}
          {{contact}}
        {{/each}}
      </td>
    </tr>
```

All I have been able to render in the table is

```
[object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]
```

or nothing. If anyone can help me out, I am new to meteor/blaze and cannot figure out how to iterate through the cursor. The mongo collection looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "Mzb6a9uh3948vw", "contact" : [ { "emailAddress" : "glen@example.com", "someContact" : "No", "creationDate" : "N/A", "bounceBack" : "N/A", "unsubscribed" : "N/A" } ] }
```

I would like to do something like this in the table:

```
        {{#each cursor}}
          {{emailAddress}}
          {{someContact}}
          {{createdDate}}
          {{bounceBack}}
          {{unsubscribed}}
        {{/each}}
```

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
//helper
contacts() {
    var contactCursor = Contacts.find();
    return contactCursor;
}

//html
{{#each contacts}} 
    {{#each contact}}
        <p>email: {{emailAddress}</p>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Also, why do you have to have it like

```
{ "_id" : "Mzb6a9uh3948vw", 
"contact" : [ { "emailAddress" : "glen@example.com", "someContact" : "No", "creationDate" : "N/A", "bounceBack" : "N/A", "unsubscribed" : "N/A" } ] 
}
```

instead of:

```
"_id" : "Mzb6a9uh3948vw", 
"emailAddress" : "glen@example.com", 
"someContact" : "No",
//the rest
```

You could then use them like `{{emailAddress}} //returns "glen@example.com"`, `{{someContact}} //returns "No"`

**EDIT**:

You could insert contacts individually to your contacts collection and return them by saving a relevant ID to each of them. Lets say its contacts of one user. You save userId in your insert then return those like:

```
Contacts.find({userId: Meteor.userId()});
```

You could also do it from your publication which I think is better in most of the cases.

Comment: Nothing renders using `{{#each contact}} 
    <p>email: {{contact.emailAddress}</p>
{{/each}} `. The mongo collection is structured like that because I had to push multiple objects into "contacts".

Comment: @BrandonBaum I edited my answer though it would be easier to write a working answer if you included your code about how you insert contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `contact` helper return a cursor whose objects nest an array whose name is also `contact`. You have to also iterate over that array:

```
{{#each contact}}
  id: {{_id}}
  {{#each this.contact}}
    email address: {{emailAddress}}
    some contact?: {{someContact}}
    creation date: {{creationdate}}
    bounce back: {{bounceBack}}
    unsubscribed?: {{unsubscribed}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```